# How to configure FFmpeg library with ndk r12 using windows 7 64 bit operating system for android

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I want to merge mp3 audio file with surfaceview recorded video in background. So after lots of research i get FFmpeg concept for achieving this kind of functionality. But i am not know how to configure Ffmpeg library with ndk in android studio using windows 7 64 bit os. So if any one can have knowledge about it so please share with me. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step 1. Install Cygwin64 **(you must be install dos2unix)**

step 2. Install android-ndk **(current version r12b)**

step 3. Install ffmpeg **(current version 3.1.1)**

step 4. Extract ffmpeg-3.1.1 in android-ndk path **(ret: d:\Android\ndk\android-ndk-r12b/ffmpeg-3.1.1)**

step 5. Execute Cygwin64 **(with Admin rights)**

step 6. Follow http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/ this page's step 2 & 3 **(you need to edit build_android.sh)**

step 7. You can see that

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QKvD.png)

Comment: When including external link try to put essential information here itself. Over the time external links might become obsolete and the answer becomes useless.

Comment: is android ndk version 9 is compulsory for ffmpeg library? No other version is useful for it?

Comment: @JeetendraChoudhary Okay. I see. I'm going to edit my answer soon.

Comment: @jack no. that page's **step 3 Build ffmpeg**, you need to edit **NDK**, **SYSROOT**, **TOOLCAIN**.

my case is
`NDK=d:/Android/ndk/android-ndk-r12b`
`SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-15/arch-arm/`
`TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64`

Comment: @Jake thanks for giving your valuable time, Thanks a lot for giving a guidance regarding ffmpeg....

Comment: @JakePark i cant get sudo command in cygwin, its "-bash: sudo: command not found" when using sudo inside cygwin. I post image in same question.

Comment: @jack not used sudo,  just "chmod +x ./file_name.sh"