# Linking shared libraries (.so) in Android Studio 2.2.2

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, cmake, java-native-interface

I am really stuck and desperate for an answer.
I have looked pretty much everywhere online to solve this problem with no real success.

Basically I have compiled ffmpeg for android and I am trying to use the (`.so`) files inside Android Studio 2.2.2.

The problem is that I keep getting this error when I try to compile my code 
Please note that my code worked perfectly under MS Visual Studio and I am certain it works as it should.

[Compile ERROR Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFFfh.png)

I am thinking this error means that I am not linking my shared libraries (`.so`) files against my `.cpp` file (correct me if I am wrong).

Things I tried:

- I have tried including my `.so` files inside `main/jniLibs`, and still didn't work.
- I put the `.so` files inside `app/libs`, and still no success.
- Provided linking rules in cmake for example:

  ```
  add_library(B SHARED IMPORTED)
  set_target_properties(B PROPERTIES
       IMPORTED_LOCATION src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libavformat-55.so
  )
  include_directories(src/main/cpp/include/)
  target_link_libraries(native-lib B)
  ```

  This gave me another error which looks like this:

  ```
  Error:error: 'src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libavformat-55.so', needed by '../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it
  ```

Here is the structure of my project tree:

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Jnt.png)

I really need help.

Comment: It is preferable to place code and errors as text over images they can be copy and pasted.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38477333/2979092 It can be fiddly and it is hard trying to find the right information about how it is done.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have already solved this problem by setting the IMPORTED_LOCATION to                                                                    C:/......./src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/libavformat-55.so