# Unable to convert cpp files to so file

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

Im trying to convert cpp files to so file. Following is my make file

```
build:
    ndk-build

install:
    cp -r libs/armeabi-v7a/*.so ../src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/
    cp -r libs/arm64-v8a/*.so ../src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/

clean:
    ndk-build clean
```

I tried running `make` but Im getting the following error,
`make: ndk-build: No such file or directory`

Ofcourse I have installed ndk in my mac. what am i missing?

Comment: Why you don't use gradle building ?

Comment: How can i do so?

Comment: can u please explain.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43673978/3580911

Comment: For more details:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/44045945/3580911

Comment: it is not working. Im trying to compile cpp files to so file. I dont have so file in advance

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? This is ndk-building via gradle. It depends on you. You can build or rebuild SO libraries.  For more and more informations, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44428645/3580911

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like your mac system doesn't know where to find ndk-build. have you updated the PATH variable or its equivalent in mac.

Alternatively try to execute ndk-build with its complete path to check if its just a PATH issue.

Also note that you need to write Android.mk and Application.mk to compile the C++ code. You can refer this blog for more details http://web.guohuiwang.com/technical-notes/androidndk1

Comment: May i know how to execute ndk-build with complete path?

Comment: just give the entire path in the terminal. <ndk  install path\ndk-build>

Comment: like `make /Users/jie/Documents/android/android-ndk-r8b`